# CodeIgniter 4 site_url returns the old domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, configuration, codeigniter-4

I made a web application with CodeIgniter 4 and moved it to another domain and also to another server. After I configured the database I went to test it and it always redirects me back to the old domain.

I checked what the `site_url()` function returns and it returns the old website.. Then I did an extensive search for all the files in my project to find where I might have a hard-coded old domain but nothing came up..

how can I fix this and where else can I change the base url?

It is probably not important but the application was previously on subdomain but now it is on main domain (test.old-domain.com vs domain.com)

Comment: You say site_url is returning the incorrect URL, so just look at its code and see where it's getting it from

Comment: ~line 19 of app/Config/App.php, see also [`baseurl()`](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#base_url)

Comment: @Vickel, if you mean baseURL property in app/Config/App.php file, then it is my new domain. But site_url() still returns old domain and i can't figure out where this property is set or how can i change it..

Comment: [*Note: Since v4.3.0, if you set Config\App::$allowedHostnames, this returns the URL with the hostname set in it if the current URL matches.*](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=site_url#site_url). You might also need to look-up your .htaccess and .env files

Comment: @Vickel yes, it was in .env file and the search was unable to find it for some reason.. Anyway, this solved my problem, thank you so much for your effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your new CodeIgniter 4 site is redirecting to an old domain, you need to check mainly 3 files:

- project-root/app/Config/App.php: check your [baseUrl()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=site_url#base_url) setting:
  around line 19, set to the new domain: `public $baseURL = 'https://myNewDomaindotcom';`:

  > Note
  >
  > Since v4.3.0, if you set Config\App::$allowedHostnames, this returns
  > the URL with the hostname set in it if the current URL matches.
- project-root/public/.htaccess:  check if you have any RewriteRule
  redirecting to the old domain
- project-root/.env: around line 25 you can enable: app.baseURL =
  'myNewDomaindotcom'

more about [Initial Configuration](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/running.html?highlight=app%20baseurl#initial-configuration)

---

concerning OP's comment:

> yes, it was in .env file and the search was unable to find it for some
> reason

depending on your favorite IDE, you might need to associate .env files with your IDE in order to have the .env file contents searched (or just search it manually)